# Lazarus - parse function based on delimiter

Tags: lazarus

I am building a small app in Lazarus and need a parse function based on the underscore. For example:

```
array := Split(string, delimiter);
```

So `string = "this_is_the_first_post"` and delimiter is the underscore resulting in the array being returned as:

```
array[0] = this
array[1] = is
array[2] = the
array[3] = first
array[4] = post
```

Any one has any idea how to go about this? I have tried a few code examples and it always throws an error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
var
  List1: TStringList;    
begin
  List1 := TStringList.Create;    
  try
    List1.Delimiter := '_';
    List1.DelimitedText := 'this_is_the_first_post';

    ShowMessage(List1[0]);
    ShowMessage(List1[1]);
    ShowMessage(List1[2]);
    ShowMessage(List1[3]);
    ShowMessage(List1[4]);
  finally
    List1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In this example the output will be shown as a set of messages but you get the general idea.

Comment: Oh, for some reason this has posted with double line breaks. If you copy and past this example into your application make sure you remove them to avoid any issue.

Comment: Thanks Todd, I can't tell you how long I have been struggling with this.

Comment: And also have a look at TStringlist.strictdelimiter. Without tstringlist will always break on space. (and most chars under ASCII 32)